# Is std::stack implemented using a double linked list?

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list, stack, doubly-linked-list

I once had a professor tell me that `std::stack` is generally implemented using a double linked-list, which would be redundant given you only need access to the top.

His conclusion was that a user-defined stack structure implemented with `std::vector` or a single linked-list would conserve memory space.

Either way, I am likely to use the STL version anyway (no use wasting energy), but does `std::stack` really waste memory like that?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I imagine that at the least it is compiler dependent.

Comment: Aren't most CPP compilers (surely yours) open source?

Comment: Good enough question, but you *can* try compiling it yourself, or using a debugger, or looking at the spec, or looking at the source code, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hear wrong, and he actually said double-ended queue, i.e. `deque`? Just look at the [declaration of `std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and it should be pretty obvious what it uses. You are planning to check the docs before using it, right?

Comment: @Aposhian, did you follow the link I gave? Does it not clearly answer your question? _"acts as a wrapper to the underlying container [...] The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. [...] The standard containers std::vector, std::deque and std::list satisfy these requirements."_ If you read that page you will see that the underlying container for a  `std::stack` (i.e. **the implementation of how std::stack actually stores it's data**) is a template parameter, so is not fixed. That's all the insight you need, surely.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Alright I see now. I did read it, but skimmed over the fact that it is a template, since I thought you were simply directing me to the interface. Thank you. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::stack` is a *container adaptor*. The implementation uses another container type, defined as a template parameter, for storage.

By default, it uses `std::deque`, which is not exactly a double linked list, though it is possible to use `std::list`.

A small amount of memory could be saved by backing it with an `std::vector`, with a potential performance cost.